# When we receive an instance of a child object as a type-hinted parameter of a parent, why do we have a child object instead of a parent object?

Tags: php, oop

A child instance was passed to the function 'f' that type-hinted by the parent class in the below code. I expected to see the parent object in the function (based on what we know from oop in c++), but with PHP, I received the child object. Could anyone explain this to me?

```php
class ParentClass
{

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{

}

function f(ParentClass $p)
{
    var_dump($p); // output: object(ChildClass)#1 (0) { }
}

f(new ChildClass);
```

Comment: From what I know about OOP in C++ you would get an instance of the child class in C++ also...

Comment: @obe When type hinting child objects to parent, shouldn't the type be changed to parent?

Comment: Objects in PHP can't change their types at run time, but it's not supposed to be a problem. An object of a derived (child) class should behave correctly in any context where an object of the parent class is needed. This is called the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: C++ is exactly the same. The _runtime_ type of an object doesn't change when you pass it to a function, regardless of the type of the formal parameter that the function expects to receive. Only the compile-time type is different.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, because ChildClass extends from ParentClass, it has all the power of ParentClass, plus whatever is implemented in ChildClass.

The function f(ParentClass $p) requires an object that [is_a($p, "ParentClass")](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php), which is satisfied by either an object of type ParentClass, or from an extension, such as ChildClass.

Any code within that specific function f(ParentClass $p) should only depend on $p having functions from the ParentClass, and not from the ChildClass.